# I want a user Registration page on wordpress with civicrm

Tags: webform-civicrm, contribution-page, user-account

I want a form with user registration and component of civicrm that i have created in civicrm. If we submit that for user data should be saved and redirected to civicrm contruibution page.

If user has paid for the membership the only he can view the members page.

Please help,

Thankyou In Advance

You can drop and answer in [email](http://mailto:jayesh@pingalasoftware.com) or [telegram](https://t.me/jayesh1306) me.

Comment: Welcome. It would be normal to provide the Answer here since that is the point of the system as it then also becomes a resource for the wider community. If you want direct one-to-one help then you may want to reach out to an Expert (but expect to be charged) https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Are you wanting a CiviCRM Profile set up to 'create user account'? Are you wanting to use that before the user proceeds to the Contribution page. If so that should be possible using out-of-the-box solution - read up on the Profile section perhaps in the documentation